# Replace multiple strings with a single sentence

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using ASP.Net and C#, how can I replace multiple string with a single one?

In my code, I use this loop to get the results, but the last argument is the only one filled.

```
    public void smssend(string CustomerName,string from,string to,string date,string time)
    {
        con.Open();

        string str1 = "select * from Master ";
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
        SqlDataReader reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader1.Read())
        {
            Label1.Text = reader1["Template"].ToString();

        }
        reader1.Close();
        string desc = Label1.Text;
        string[] BadCharacters = { "1", "2", "3", "4","5" };
        string[] GoodCharacters = { CustomerName, from, to, date,time };
        string strReplaced = "";

        int i;
        for(i=0; i<=4; i++)
        {
            strReplaced = desc.Replace(BadCharacters[i], GoodCharacters[i]);

        }
        Label1.Text = strReplaced;
```

**Output:**

```
1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 12:00:00
```

How can I concatenate the multiple strings appropriately?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: needd to fill all data like customername, from ,to ,date, time.. but time only filled..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're  overwriting `strReplaced` in each loop run.  It seems like you want this instead:

```
    for(i=0; i<=4; i++)
    {
        desc = desc.Replace(BadCharacters[i], GoodCharacters[i]);
    }
    Label1.Text = desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

try assigning the result of each replacement to `strReplaced`

```
string strReplaced = desc;

int i;
for(i=0; i<=4; i++)
{
    strReplaced = strReplaced.Replace(BadCharacters[i], GoodCharacters[i]);
}
Label1.Text = strReplaced;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<=4; i++)
{
   strReplaced = **desc**.Replace(BadCharacters[i], GoodCharacters[i]);
}
```

Replace it with this:

```
int i;
var strReplaced  = desc;
for(i=0; i<=4; i++)
{
  strReplaced = **strReplaced**.Replace(BadCharacters[i], GoodCharacters[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code from the rest of these answers are good, but just a note. If you're replacing everything in one string with a for loop, then when you overwrite your BadCharacter values with the date, the iteration after that might replace the numbers in your date with the GoodCharacter value from your time variable. To get around this, I suggest changing the values for your BadCharacter array to something a bit more unique so you don't risk overwriting good values.

Answer (score 0):

Would String.Join be something you're looking for? It will allow you to concat multiple strings with a specified separator.